# Oracle trigger before insert is not inserting

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-insert

Hi im using triggers with two tables, **tableA, tableB**.
In *tableA* before insert trigger i insert in *tableB* some values from new record, in *tableB* i have before insert trigger and it generate a value for new record on *tableB*.
When i insert in *tbaleA* it works well my new row is in the table, but in *tableB* no data is inserted, if i disable trigger on *tableB* all the records inserted before are commited.

i think the transaction never ends in tableB's trigger but i dont know why, can you help me please?
Here is my triggers:
TableA

```
create or replace TRIGGER  TG_A             
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLEA         
FOR EACH ROW                                        
BEGIN                                                
  BEGIN
      insert into tableB (name,date) values (:new.name,sysdate);
end;

end;
```

TableB

```
create or replace TRIGGER  TG_B             
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLEB
FOR EACH ROW                                        
BEGIN                                                
  BEGIN
      IF :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN             
      :NEW.ID:=SEQ_TableB.NEXTVAL;
    END IF;  

  end;

end;
```

Regards

Comment: All of the inserts will be in the same session, so you can't have the new table A rows visible to one session but the table B rows not visible to that session. (Even with an autonomous transaction I can't see how it could behave as you describe.) It sounds like you actually aren't looking at *new* A records at all, when you see the discrepancy. Did you perhaps already have A records, and after setting up B and the triggers, you deleted and reinserted the same values - and from another session you can't see the difference? (Disabling the trigger is DDL so commits - *both* tables...)

Comment: Your code [works as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9a91a82f65e3af0d47edcbf3ea9d965b), incidentally - though that is querying in the same session, which you don't seem to be doing.

Comment: I think you'd better to use `insert into tableB (id,name,date) values (seq_tableB.nextval,:new.name,sysdate)` within `TG_A`, while getting rid of `TG_B`.